# c++ however to avoid deep copy issue

Tags: c++, performance

for the below code demo, I send a reference into a class, and add some items to the vector, then return the vector, I think there is copy issue in the assignment **test = a.return_data()** in the main function, is there some method to improve the efficiency?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A 
{
public:
    A(vector<int> &a);
    void additem(int c);
    vector<int> return_data();
private:
    vector<int> d;
};

A::A(vector<int> &a)
  {
      d = a;
  }

void A::additem(int c)
{
      d.push_back(c);
}

vector<int> A::return_data()
{
    return d;
}

void main()
{
    vector<int> test;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        test.push_back(i);
    }
    cout << test.size() << endl;
    A a(test);
    a.additem(10);
    test = a.return_data();
    cout << test.size() << endl;
}
```

Comment: "I send a reference into a class", but you perform a copy assignment anyway, so the (non-const) reference is useless. It should be a const reference at the very least, or better, take it by value instead of reference if you're intending to copy it anyway.

Comment: Yes, `d = a` and `return d` would both have to copy the vector. If that is a problem, depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: _"is there some method to improve the efficiency?"_ What makes you sure that this will be inefficient? Did you measure? Also if you really only need a reference, provide a reference variable as member.

Comment: Do you need the vector to be *strictly owned* by your class until you return it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hold a reference member in the class,

```
class A 
{
... ...
private:
    vector<int>& d;
};
```

And then use [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to initialize it in ctor,

```
A::A(vector<int> &a) : d(a) {}
```

And then no need to use `return_data()` anymore,

```
void main()
{
    vector<int> test;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        test.push_back(i);
    }
    cout << test.size() << endl;
    A a(test);
    a.additem(10);
    // test = a.return_data();
    cout << test.size() << endl;
}
```

[LIVE](http://ideone.com/iaWmFZ)

NOTE: Make sure the reference will not be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need your class to exclusively own the vector you might simply get away with a reference (and render `return_data` obsolete)

```
class A {
public:
  A(vector<int> &a);
  void additem(int c);
private:
  vector<int>& d; // Just store a reference
};

A::A(vector<int> &a) : d(a) {}

int main() {
  vector<int> test;

  for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    test.push_back(i);
  }
  cout << test.size() << endl;
  A a(test);
  a.additem(10);
  cout << test.size() << endl;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6baba34d5ff663cc)</kbd>

Anyway, if you do need to deal with ownership (following the [rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)) you could use `unique_ptr`s and move them around

```
class A {
public:
  A(unique_ptr<vector<int>>&& a);
  void additem(int c);
  unique_ptr<vector<int>> return_data();
private:
  unique_ptr<vector<int>> d; // Unique owner of the vector
};

A::A(unique_ptr<vector<int>>&& a) : 
  d(forward<unique_ptr<vector<int>>>(a))
{}

unique_ptr<vector<int>> A::return_data() {
  return move(d); // Moves the member vector (can no longer be used)
}

int main() {
  unique_ptr<vector<int>> test = make_unique<vector<int>>();;

  for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    test->push_back(i);
  }
  cout << test->size() << endl;
  A a(move(test));
  a.additem(10);
  test = a.return_data();
  cout << test->size() << endl;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3acf5c34bf5bba6)</kbd>

In both cases no copies are necessary and thus even for large vectors it should prove to be faster than your approach. Keep in mind that the latter approach is *one-shot-only*, i.e. you don't get to return multiple copies of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of return_data you could simply let the user of the function pass an argument, which you will take by reference.

```
void get_data(std::vector<int> &vec)
{
    //Now you can either copy or move
    vec = d;
    //or
    vec = std::move(d);
}
```

You cannot always be sure, that the element of the reference being hold in the class still exists later.